# Menu Selection in LaTeX

Tags: conditionals

I want to create a menu selection for different documents, what I mean for example is to run latex over the terminal, and the terminal prompt you if you want to create a diploma, a letter, a book, etc.

Later using the \typein command fill the documents previously done. I already know how to use the \typein command. But the menu I have no idea, is this even possible in LaTeX?

Comment: It really is not appropriate to ask for help with homework here. Your teacher wants to see what *you* have learnt and what *you* can do. It is a waste of everybody's time for your teacher to mark the combined efforts of the users here, and it undermines efforts to adapt teaching to students' current levels of knowledge and understanding. Depending on the context, it may also constitute a violation of your institution's academic code i.e. it may also be cheating.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a homework question.

Comment: I agree, but we did not see any of this. We only see the basics. This is not intended to justify myself, but I was looking for this for more than a week and I did not find how I could do that, or well I did not know how to look for this. Sorry about my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this at the start of your interactive file:

```
\typein[\choice]{What kind of document are you creating?^^J
type a for article^^J
type b for book^^J
}
\if a\choice
  \documentclass{article}
\else 
  \if b\choice
    \documentclass{book}
  \fi
\fi
```

This is a little easier to code if you give the user only numerical options:

```
\typein[\choice]{What kind of document are you creating?^^J
type 0 for article^^J
type 1 for book^^J
type 2 for letter
}
\ifcase \choice
  \documentclass{article}
\or
  \documentclass{book}
\or
  \documentclass{letter}
\fi
```

Follow that with any other prompts. The macro `\choice` can be any legal macro name and can be different for each `\typein` prompt so you can save all the data for later construction of the document. You don't necessarily need `\typein` for the body of the document: at some point you can turn everything over to the user with something like:

```
\typeout{Now type in your article/book/letter, ending 
with "\string\end{document}"}
\endinput
```

Comment: I do not think it is helpful to post answers to other people's homework, and I'd really encourage you to consider whether this is something you want to be doing.